# Django un managed models

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a model for a view with

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
```

Now for superuser the model displays in the admin. But I cannot set permissions for the staff.
No unmanaged models are visible in the user permissions.

What am i missing?

Django Version :1.6.2

Comment: Did you do syncdb? You still need to, to create the entries in the permissions table.

Comment: yes i did that. But the unmanaged models are not synced. FYI I am using South.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove south in settings before syncdb or run `syncdb --all`